# VSTS Build - Choose which unit tests run depending on which files were modified in a pull request

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to control which unit tests run in a VSTS build pipeline based on which files were modified in the PR that triggered the pipeline.

Is there a way to detect which files were modified in a pull request during a VSTS build triggered for that PR, and then choose which tests to run based on that information?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible:

### Manual Approach

One approach to this is to have a custom Powershell task in your pipeline that sets a variable based on whether a certain file was changed in the last commit. So you might have a pipeline like this:

[image: Example build pipeline]

Your 'Set criteria for files in last commit' step would contain an inline powershell script to set a Build variable depending on whether a certain string was within the list of files from the last commit, where 'YOURFILE.cs' is the file you are interested in (you could replace this with any logic):

```
$ChangedFiles = & git show --pretty="" --name-only

if ($ChangedFiles -like '*YOURFILE.cs*') {
    Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunTests;]true")
 }
else{
     Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunTests;]false")
}
```

Then, in your 'Run tests' step, you can set a conditional control option which will look at this variable to decide whether or not to run that set of tests:

[image: Custom control option]

### Visual Studio Test Impact Analysis

If you are using the Visual Studio Test task to run your tests, there is also a built in option to only run the tests that are impacted by the build, via the Test Impact Analysis feature.

[image: Impacted tests]

This may be of use to you but doesn't directly answer your specific question and has a wider scope. More information is available [on the Azure Devops documentation pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/test-impact-analysis?view=vsts)

Comment: This is close to what I intend. If I read your "manual" answer correctly, it will run ALL tests in a project if particular files are modified in the commit. Is there some way to specify a list of tests instead? In other words, I want the output of the Powershell script to be a list of the test methods to run. For example:

If file "foo.cs" is modified, then run test method "foo_test".
If file "bar.*.cs" is mofified, then run test methods "bar_*_test".